# Retrieve parent child records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, parent-child, master-detail

I have two tables `Trade` and `Trade Details` like this:

**Trade** table:

```
ID    Portfolio   Source   Version     Createdon   Status
---------------------------------------------------------
1     Test1       RIM      1.0         2016-01-20    1
2     Test2       iOS      1.0         2016-01-20    1
```

**Trade Details** table:

```
ID   TradeID    Ticker   Company     Shares     Action  Comments
----------------------------------------------------------------
1      1        MSFT     Microsoft     100        Buy      Test
2      1        IBM      IBM           200        Sell     Test
3      2        Yahoo    Yahoo Inc     50         Sell     Test
4      2        Goog     Google Inc    500        Buy      Test
```

I want to retrieve and show the data in the following format.

**Output**

```
1     Test1       RIM      1.0         2016-01-20    1
1      1        MSFT     Microsoft     100        Buy      Test
2      1        IBM      IBM           200        Sell     Test
2     Test2       iOS      1.0         2016-01-20    1
3      2        Yahoo    Yahoo Inc     50         Sell     Test
4      2        Goog     Google Inc    500        Buy      Test
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use union between the two tables, and add additional columns customized, to set the desired order to generate the required output

**ex [in oracle syntax, but the idea is the same]**

```
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN OID = 0 THEN TO_CHAR(P_TradeID) ELSE Portfolio END AS TradeID, Portfolio, Ticker, Company,SHARES, Action, Comments
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID AS OID, 1 AS SOID,
            TradeID AS P_TradeID,
            TO_CHAR(ID) AS Portfolio, -- important to change to datatype of columns to be matching in the union in order for the union statement to work
            Ticker,
            Company,
            TO_CHAR(SHARES) SHARES,
            TO_CHAR(Action) Action,
            Comments
        FROM
        (
            --here will be your select statement.... the below is just a demo
            SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS TradeID, 'MSFT'  AS Ticker, 'Microsoft'  AS Company, 100 AS SHARES, 'Buy'  AS Action, 'Test' AS Comments FROM DUAL UNION
            SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS TradeID, 'IBM'   AS Ticker, 'IBM'        AS Company, 200 AS SHARES, 'Sell' AS Action, 'Test' AS Comments FROM DUAL UNION
            SELECT 3 AS ID, 2 AS TradeID, 'Yahoo' AS Ticker, 'Yahoo Inc'  AS Company, 50  AS SHARES, 'Sell' AS Action, 'Test' AS Comments FROM DUAL UNION
            SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS TradeID, 'Goog'  AS Ticker, 'Google Inc' AS Company, 500 AS SHARES, 'Buy'  AS Action, 'Test' AS Comments FROM DUAL
        )

        UNION --the trick is with the union here

        SELECT
            0 AS OID,0 AS SOID, --and the order columns here and in the above query
            ID AS P_TradeID,
            Portfolio,
            Source AS Ticker,
            Version AS Company,
            TO_CHAR(Createdon) AS SHARES,
            TO_CHAR(Status) AS Action,
            '' AS Comments
        FROM
        (
            --and again, make sure the datatype of the columns are the same!
            SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Test1' AS Portfolio, 'RIM' Source, '1.0' AS Version, '2016-01-20' AS Createdon, 1 AS Status  FROM DUAL UNION
            SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Test2' AS Portfolio, 'iOS' Source, '1.0' AS Version, '2016-01-20' AS Createdon, 1 AS Status  FROM DUAL
        )
    )
    ORDER BY 
        P_TradeId, SOID, OID
```

**This will generate the following:**

```
1 | Test1   | RIM   |   1.0         | 2016-01-20 |  1       | 
1 | 1       | MSFT  |   Microsoft   | 100        |  Buy     | Test
2 | 2       | IBM   |   IBM         | 200        |  Sell    | Test
2 | Test2   | iOS   |   1.0         | 2016-01-20 |  1       | 
3 | 3       | Yahoo |   Yahoo Inc   | 50         |  Sell    | Test
4 | 4       | Goog  |   Google Inc  | 500        |  Buy     | Test
```

---

**See [this SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/7365/0) for sql-server-2008 syntax**

Comment: I can provide you with the sql-server syntax if you need, but the differences will be small, it will be almost identical

Comment: It would be great if you can provide me the sql server syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VijayVSTO, check the sql fiddle link that I added for sql-server syntax.

Comment: Thanks simsim for your help.